# Delete sql table data then insert multiple variable amount of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone help please?
trying to create a page for calendar entries for a band that they can update themselves on their own site.

html entry page:

```
<form action="addgigtimes.php" method="POST">
<fieldset class='multi'>
<legend><h5>Gig 1</h5></legend>

<label for='weekday' class='accessAid'></label>
<select id='weekday' name='weekday'>
<option value='' selected>Day of week</option>
<option value='Monday'>Monday</option>
<option value='Tuesday'>Tuesday</option>
<option value='Wednesday'>Wednesday</option>
<option value='Thursday'>Thursday</option>
<option value='Friday'>Friday</option>
<option value='Saturday'>Saturday</option>
<option value='Sunday'>Sunday</option></select>



<label for='day' class='accessAid'></label>
<select id='day' name='day'><option value='' selected>--Day--</option>
<option value='01'>01</option>
<option value='02'>02</option>
<option value='03'>03</option>
<option value='04'>04</option>
<option value='05'>05</option>
<option value='06'>06</option>
<option value='07'>07</option>
<option value='08'>08</option>
<option value='09'>09</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
  <option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
<option value='23'>23</option>
<option value='24'>24</option>
<option value='25'>25</option>
<option value='26'>26</option>
<option value='27'>27</option>
<option value='28'>28</option>
<option value='29'>29</option>
<option value='30'>30</option>
<option value='31'>31</option></select>

<label for='month' class='accessAid'></label>
<select id='month' name='month'><option value='' selected>--Month--</option>
<option value='01'>01 (Jan)</option>
<option value='02'>02 (Feb)</option>
<option value='03'>03 (Mar)</option>
<option value='04'>04 (Apr)</option>
<option value='05'>05 (May)</option>
<option value='06'>06 (Jun)</option>
<option value='07'>07 (Jul)</option>
<option value='08'>08 (Aug)</option>
<option value='09'>09 (Sep)</option>
<option value='10'>10 (Oct)</option>
<option value='11'>11 (Nov)</option>
<option value='12'>12 (Dec)</option></select>

<label for='year' class='accessAid'></label><select id='year' name='year'>
<option value='' selected>--Year--</option>
 <option value='2015'>2015</option>
<option value='2016'>2016</option>
</select>    
 venue
<input type="text" class="input"  name="venue" />
location
<input type="text" class="input"  name="location" />
time
<input type="text" class="input"  name="time" />
</fieldset>

<button type="reset" style="border: 0; background: transparent"> 
<img src="images/reset.jpg"  alt="reset" style="margin-right:19px "/> 
</button>
<button type="submit" value="submit" style="border: 0; background:transparent"> 
<img src="images/submit.jpg"  alt="submit" /> 
</button>
</form>
```

I will repeat the fieldset code 30 times so the band can enter a max of 30 gigs at once.

here is the php code:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM gigtimes";

$weekday = $_POST['weekday'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$venue = $_POST['venue'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$time = $_POST['time'];


$rt=mysql_query("insert into guestbook(weekday,day,month,year,venue,location,time) VALUES      ('$weekday','$day','$month','$year','$venue','$location','$time')");
echo mysql_error();
```

So basically delete whats already on the database then update.
I'm just not sure how to go about the row ids? Could anyone explain.
Thanks,
Bettsy

Comment: What do you mean "*I'm just not sure how to go about the row ids*"? Just make them `auto_increment` integers. You might also want to add an `band_id` if the app is also for multiple bands.

Answer (score 0):

I have a band like website in production, so I know your pain. One thing I do is insert the band name as well, so that way if the band wants to delete something, it searches for their name and deletes the field such as:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM gigtimes WHERE band_name = '$band_name'";
```

It's not perfect, because in theory there *could* be multiple bands with the same name, so to prevent that, make band names unique. This works perfectly for me. Let me know if you need more information.